# Defining the nearest Google data center location using cloud shell

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

Is there a quick way to get the nearest data center location which is nearest to you at the moment using cloud shell?

Or probably there's a better ways to do that in GCP? Thanks!

Comment: there is, more or less 1 region per country/state. Why the requirement?

Comment: You can run 'gcloud compute regions list' to get the full list of compute Engine Region, https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/regions/list

Answer (score 0):

You can find out the [region where you Cloud Shell VM is currently located](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/how-cloud-shell-works#zone_selection) by accessing GCP instance metadata endpoint within Cloud Shell:

```sh
curl metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/zone
```